# How to get a value from a textbox and assign it to a variable using TimeValue()

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im coding in vba in ms-access and Im wondering how to address a value that appears in a text box in my mai form and put that value in a variable.TimeValue ("value") for example..... I tried with this code but it doesn't work..

```
    dDuration = TimeValue("me.text101.text")
```

me.text101.text = is the textbox holding the value, the value is in minutes:seconds...
dDuration = the variable that will be asigned the value from texbox101.text..I also tried me.textbox101.value... but it just freezes, meaning that it goes to an infinite loop calculating...Is this the correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
dDuration = TimeValue(Me.text101)
```

Freezing is another issue, not related to this code.

Comment: yeah it almost worked but now I get #Type! in return... If I just put a number like an hour (dDuration =TimeValue ("1:00") ) It does the process right but if I say dDuration = TimeValue ("[Text101]") or dDuration = TimeValue ([Text101]) it just freezes... I just wanna tell calculate me the cbo box depending on what's on Text101....I know Im near...

Comment: Ok I solved my problem... the problem was that I was telling the program to convert me seconds into minutes and mminutes into hours...